# How to not get repeated values with gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview to insert values to the database dynamically..

i have one dropdownlist for selecting employee id and one textbox for getting personnel details...

dropdownlist values are getting from database using select query and binding those values into dropdownlist which exists in gridview

personnel details text box values entered by user for each employee

if one employee selects from dropdownlist and inserts details into textbox after submitting his details his empid must hide in that dropdownlist...for not getting multiple rows about the employee.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMPID>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="empid" runat="server" Width="100px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMPID>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="txtbox" runat="server" width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="Add_Details" runat="server" Text="Add Details" OnClick="Addhour_Click"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

in the above empid is the dropdownlist which binds data from database...
and txtbox is used to get the personneldetails about the empid selected from dropdownlist empid...

after selecting one id from dropdownlist and entering some data into text if we click to add details button the details are storing into database correctly and inserting another row into gridview..
but again already inserted empid also displaying in that dropdownlist...
how to remove that item from dropdownlist after inserting data into database for perticular emp..id.. thanks in advance.. please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really hide id from dropdown then you can add field (may be `bit` datatype and name as `addedRecord`) in the table from where Id is coming. set that field if record is added and bind drop down with only ids that are not set. Otherwise you can check in database before adding personnel info, if that exists then don't insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Use your postback correctly 
Give this in your pageload()
  `if(!postback)`

```
 {  

ddlbindcode();//dropdownlist bind query   

}
```

Comment: i am not getting repeator values in dropdownlist